# Input/output from bash script's subshell

Tags: python, bash

I need to execute a tcsh script and then a python script in the same subshell.

I'm left with something like:

`$(/bin/tcsh -c "source $tcshScript && python3 $pythonScript")`

How can I use the python's input and print in the terminal?
Any way to pass the stdin and stdout to the python script?

(The input seems to be working!! When I use input() the prompt waits for me to type, then Enter and it receives the input.)

Since it was way quicker to learn bash than tcsh I did the wrapper script in bash.

Answer (score 0):

I've created a simple example and that works for me. You need to pipe the output to your script:

```py
try:
    while True:
        s = input()
        print("got {} ".format(s))
except EOFError:
    print("reached end")
    pass
```

Using the script:

```bash
$ seq 1 100 | python3 tst.py
got 1
got 2
...
got 99 
got 100 
reached end
```

Comment: Note: You're using `$()` wrong. It means that you want to execute the output of the command. See `$(echo ls)`